# Ubuntu 14.04 (linaro) seahorse (gnome keyring) fails to store unlock passphrase of ssh key

Tags: ssh, password, gnome-keyring, ssh-agent

I have a hard time telling seahorse 3.10.2 to store the unlock passphrase for my ssh key.

With Ubuntu 10.04 one had to invoke the following command:

```
/usr/lib/seahorse/seahorse-ssh-askpass id_rsa
```

With Ubuntu 12.04, all that was needed was to ssh once, it would pop up a dialog in which one ticked a check-box & enter the password, and magick, it would store the pw forever.

With Ubuntu 14.04 (Linaro, arm) I seem to have no luck with either method and can't seem to find the right method to store my ssh key password.

**EDIT:** Seems like my configuration is broken somewhere as using ssh just prompts me for my passphrase at the terminal. I can use ssh-add, but it onlymstores it for the duration of the session.

Any help appreciated.